# Creating a Custom Control Checkbox ( ControlValueAccessor)

Tags: angular

I'm trying to create a custom checkbox by implementing `ControlValueAccessor`. The custom checkbox accepts one of two string values 'Y' or 'N'. To make it work on a checkbox I created an internal `ngModel` within the custom component that will convert the value ('Y' or 'N') into a boolean value and return it back from boolean to string.

Here's the code.

```
import { Component, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
import { NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, ControlValueAccessor } from '@angular/forms';

const noop = () => {
};

export const CUSTOM_INPUT_CONTROL_VALUE_ACCESSOR: any = {
    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => CustomCheckboxComponent),
    multi: true
};

@Component({
  selector: 'custom-checkbox',
  templateUrl: '<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="internalCheckbox">',
  providers: [CUSTOM_INPUT_CONTROL_VALUE_ACCESSOR]
})
export class CustomCheckboxComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {

   internalChecbox: boolean = false;

   //Placeholders for the callbacks which are later providesd
    //by the Control Value Accessor
    private onTouchedCallback: () => void = noop;
    private onChangeCallback: (_: any) => void = noop;

    //get accessor
    get value(): any {
      return this.internalChecbox == true ? 'Y' : 'N';
    };

    //set accessor including call the onchange callback
    set value(value: any) {
       this.internalChecbox = value=='Y' ? true: false;
    }

    //Set touched on blur
    onBlur() {
        this.onTouchedCallback();
    }

    //From ControlValueAccessor interface
    writeValue(value: any) {
        if (value !== this.internalChecbox) {
            this.internalChecbox = value;
        }
    }

    //From ControlValueAccessor interface
    registerOnChange(fn: any) {
        this.onChangeCallback = fn;
    }

    //From ControlValueAccessor interface
    registerOnTouched(fn: any) {
        this.onTouchedCallback = fn;
    }


}
```

I don't know why it's not working and I always get a null value.

Comment: read this article [Never again be confused when implementing ControlValueAccessor in Angular forms](https://blog.angularindepth.com/never-again-be-confused-when-implementing-controlvalueaccessor-in-angular-forms-93b9eee9ee83)

Comment: I'am wondering, how the view is working for you, cause you have an error in the `@Component` decorator. This: `templateUrl: '<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="internalCheckbox">',` should be: `template: '<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="internalCheckbox">',`. change `templateUrl` to: `template`

Comment: Note the article linked by @MaxKoretskyi has moved to a new URL - [Never again be confused when implementing ControlValueAccessor in Angular forms](https://indepth.dev/posts/1055/never-again-be-confused-when-implementing-controlvalueaccessor-in-angular-forms).

Answer (score 0):

The onChangeCallback function is never called. That's the only way for angular to know that the value in your custom component has changed and it needs to be updated in the form. So you need to execute that function whenever the value in your component is updated like this:

```
this.onChangeCallback(this.internalCheckbox);
```